# How to create Event Invoice with zero amount owing

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, webform-civicrm

Our event uses webform for registrations.
Some delegates receive 100% discounts that reduces the cost to zero.

In these cases CiviCRM does not create or send an invoice - is this standard, and is there a way to force an invoice even if the amount payable is zero?

Using latest D7 and current Civi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution.

CiviCRM will create a zero invoice (as indicated by @Ramesh in the comments).

But we found that webform_civicrm doesn't create a Civi contribution (and hence no invoice) if totalContribution evaluates as true (not 0).

To fix it my dev changed the file includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc
In webform_civicrm version: 7.x-5.8 it's at line 165.

Changed this

> ```
> if (empty($this->ent['contribution'][1]['id']) && **$this->totalContribution**) {
>   $this->createDeferredPayment();
> }
> ```
>
> to this
>
> ```
> if (empty($this->ent['contribution'][1]['id']) && **count($this->line_items**)) {
>   $this->createDeferredPayment();
> }
> ```

$this->totalContribution refers to the total amount after adding up the line items (when contribution amount is used it serves as a line item)

Answer (score 0):

when you register for an Event using discount code - even the amount is Zero CiviCRM will create an Invoice and it will send a email to the member

If this behavior is not working in your version then try upgrading to the latest version

login to https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/
username/password: demo/demo

I have created a example - which has an Invoice too

I guess this helps !!!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ramesh - good to know that Civi should generate a zero invoice. I can't fully check the functionality in the demo site because we are using webform for the registration and I wonder if that may have an impact? We've also edited the default Contributions - Invoice message template so perhaps we changed something by mistake there.

Comment: @DavyIvins try to register the event using CiviCRM link without webform - where you can test the functionality first then once you know CiviCRM is working correctly then test with Drupal webform - If you need help feel free to ask me - Thanks

Comment: Hi Ramesh - we found the cause of the missing invoice. Posted it as an answer. Thanks for your help